# How to make a sidebar move into view and stay at the top using jquery.transit

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I am using [jquery.transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) transition to move a sidebar into view on button click and I nearly got it to work, except it appears under 'leftpad' div instead of showing beside it. This is probably because I had to use position:relative in the css for the transition to work. If I use fixed position the sidebar doesn't appear at all but the 'leftpad' element moves to make a space for it. I don't know how to fix this.

Here is my code:

```
$('#openNav').click(function() {
  $("#leftpad").transition({'padding-left': "300px"},400);
  $("#contentArea").transition({'width':'95%','display':'inline-block'},400);
  $("#sidebar").transition({ x: '300px', y:'0px' });
  $("#openNav").hide();
});

 $('#closeNav').click(function() {
  $("#leftpad").transition({'padding-left': "0px"},400)
  $("#contentArea").transition({'width':'70%','display':'block'},400);
  $("#sidebar").transition({ x: '-300px', y: '0px' });
  $("#openNav").show();
});
```

Here is the css:

```
#leftpad{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#sidebar {
    height: 100%;
    width: 300px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: -300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Here is the html:

```
<div id="leftpad">
<header role="banner" class="banner_image boxshadowM enclosure1" >
        <div class="gradient2">
            <button id="openNav"  class="button1 boxshadowM">&#9776;</button>
        <h1><strong id="sitetitle">Blockpress</strong></h1>
        <h2 id="tagline"></h2>
        </div>
  </header>
<div id="contentArea" class="boxshadowM enclosure2"></div>
</div>
 <div  id="sidebar" class="enclosure3">
   <button id="closeNav" class="button2">&times;</button>
     <nav>...</nav>
     <footer>...</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is `#openNav` element in your `html` ? Also you have two unclosed tags

Comment: I copied the HTML badly. Apologies. I edited the question, It should be clear now.

Comment: I presume jquery.transit is a reference to this library: http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/ You should probably edit to mention that...

Comment: Thanks for a good suggestion. The link is added now.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this is quite simple. First, in the css, the value for `position` needs to change from `relative` to `fixed`. Next the operators in the `#sidebar` transition needs to change. Instead of `-` it should be `-=`. The same is true for the positive value. I removed the `y` value as it doesn't do anything.

See the code below:

```
$('#openNav').click(function() {
  $("#sidebar").transition({ x: '+=300px' });
  $("#leftpad").transition({'padding-left': "300px"},400);
  $("#contentArea").transition({'width':'95%','display':'inline-block'},400);
  $("#openNav").hide();
});

$('#closeNav').click(function() {
  console.log('closenav');
  $("#sidebar").transition({ x :'-=300px' });
  $("#leftpad").transition({'padding-left': "0"},400)
  $("#contentArea").transition({'width':'70%','display':'block'},400);
  $("#openNav").show();
});
```